# How to delete the rows with the max of column values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables for my source control database - `PRJ` and  `PRJHIST`, both having the same columns and constraints.

For example. `PRJ` and `PRJHIST` have the following rows

```
PRJ TABLE    

PRJ_NAME PRJ_TYPE PRJ_VERSION PRJ_AUTHOR PRJ_LANG  
PRJ001     SCRIPT   3           MARK       PERL  
PRJ002     SCRIPT   2           JACK       KSH  
PRJ003     BINARY   4           JADE       C++  


PRJHIST TABLE  

PRJ_NAME PRJ_TYPE PRJ_VERSION PRJ_AUTHOR PRJ_LANG
PRJ001     SCRIPT   1           MARK       PERL  
PRJ001     SCRIPT   2           MARK       PERL  
PRJ001     SCRIPT   3           MARK       PERL  
PRJ002     SCRIPT   1           JACK       KSH  
PRJ002     SCRIPT   2           JACK       KSH  
PRJ003     BINARY   1           JADE       C++  
PRJ003     BINARY   2           JADE       C++  
PRJ003     BINARY   3           JADE       C++  
PRJ003     BINARY   4           JADE       C++
```

The `PRJ` table always has the row with the max version from the `PRJHIST` Table

How do I delete all rows with the `max(PRJ_VERSION)` in the `PRJHIST` Table?

i.e I need to delete the below rows from the `PRJHIST` table

```
PRJ001     SCRIPT   3           MARK       PERL  
PRJ002     SCRIPT   2           JACK       KSH  
PRJ003     BINARY   4           JADE       C++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM PRJHIST a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' 
                 FROM PRJ b
                WHERE a.PRJ_NAME = b.PRJ_NAME
                  AND a.PRJ_VERSION = b.PRJ_VERSION);
```

Comment: Thanks Annjawn. I will try this and reply tomorrow. The EXIST clause should help my cause.